# Creating sidebar help information for Python script tools of ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, python-script-tool, documentation

I have been creating custom tools (Python script tools) using Python with the ArcPy module.

I can set up the tool successfully with parameters and all, but I cannot figure out how to create help text that shows up on the sidebar of the tool like the standard ArcGIS tools have?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In ArcGIS Desktop 9.3.1 and prior, right-click on the tool in ArcToolbox and select Edit Documentation.

At version 10 it is a little bit different, this thread on Esri Support describes the issue: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/405-Beta-10-ArcToolbox-Documentation

Specifically, at 10.0, you need to access the toolbox item from the Catalog window *within* ArcMap 10 - it doesn't work from ArcCatalog itself. Right click on the individual tool, select Item Description, then click Edit.

Comment: Just an additional note, in 10.1 at least, you can access sidebar help the same way as ArcGIS 9.x. You don't need ArcCatalog.