# How to Edit custom help in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, metadata

I have created a model in ArcGIS ModelBuilder with a certain number of layers specified as parameters. When I launch the model from the tool-box, I would like to edit the information in the right hand panel (and replace "no description"). That way I can give information to the users using the model.

Do you know how I can edit that part?

Comment: You might wanna check out the answer to [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10300/how-to-create-sidebar-help-information-for-custom-arcgis-script-tools) question. /M.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's an issue with editing the help for a model that makes it very difficult and unintuitive to do in ArcGIS 10.0

You have to first select the tool in the **Catalog Tree**, then right click the tool and select 'Item Description' in the **ArcToolbox pane**.  You have to do it *in that order.*  Then edit it like you would edit any metadata item.   It is best to do this when ArcMap is not open, as any changes that are made in ArcCatalog will not be reflected in ArcMap until ArcMap is closed.

See: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/8466-How-do-you-document-a-process-in-model-builder-for-ArcGIS-10?p=64778&viewfull=1#post64778

Comment: As I mentioned in the other question, in ArcGIS 10.1 you can edit the sidebar help in ArcMap without needing to use ArcCatalog, or the ArcCatalog window. Just right-click on the model in ArcToolbox and left-click on Item Description.

Comment: I agree with @Baltok - I have found this easy to do from the Catalog window of ArcMap

Comment: 10.0 had some initial issues with editing this information, and it was fixed for 10.1